# Count Number of rows with negative integers in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a timestamp column in my DB and i want to sum the number of rows that are passed due, let me show you the query for that!

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `Opened`, NOW()) as PastDue FROM `Task`
```

not this query returns the perfect result and return all rows where past due is negative and others are positive

now i want to count the number of negative rows so i did

```
SELECT COUNT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `Opened`, NOW())) < 0 as PastDue FROM `Task`
```

it currently returns **0** now there are two rows with negative result so it should return two but it always returns **0** , can anyone point out what i am missing?

Comment: `count(..) < 0` is never true, because `count(..)` can't be negative.

Comment: i tried sum as well but that always return 1

Comment: SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `Opened`, NOW())) < 0 as PastDue FROM `Task`

Comment: The solution is much simpler than you think. You are heading the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
COUNT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `Opened`, NOW())) < 0
```

is a boolean expression (checking whether the `COUNT` is less than 0), which will always return 0 (false) since a `COUNT` must be at least `0`. What you can do instead is `SUM` the results of the test (since MySQL treats booleans as 0 or 1 in a numeric context):

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `Opened`, NOW()) < 0) as PastDue FROM `Task`
```

Note that you can simplify this query to just compare `Opened` with `NOW()`, either in the `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM(`Opened` > NOW()) AS PastDue
FROM `Task`
```

or using `COUNT(*)` with a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS PastDue
FROM `Task`
WHERE `Opened` > NOW()
```

Note that based on the wording of your question, you probably want to change the condition from

```
`Opened` > NOW()
```

to

```
`Opened` < NOW()
```

Comment: C'mon Nick. Is that your query for "Count rows with timestamp in the past"?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel fair comment - I was focused on the problem with OPs query, not the fact that it was inefficient. I've updated...

Comment: @PaulSpiegel note that as written the query is "timestamp in the future"

Comment: It's not only about performance - It's about simplicity. Why not use the trivial way with `count(*)` and a WHERE clause?

Comment: :-) - And yea right - the query says timestamp is in the future, but the text says "rows that are passed due" - hmm..

Comment: @PaulSpiegel the advantage of the `SUM` without `WHERE` is that it also allows computing the non-pastdue (or in this case, actually pastdue) count at the same time.

Comment: Fair enough :-)